# QGIS keeps crashing when loading files from external drive

Tags: qgis

I am running QGIS 3.16 in M1 MacBook Air (2020).

I am having trouble when loading files (rasters -.tiff) from my external drive to QGIS. I was able to work fine for about a week, but accidentally unplugged the drive without ejecting it properly from OSX and I think that cause some kind of corruption to the files that were loaded into QGIS at that moment.

Now, when I try to load the project again, the software crashes. But if I unplug the drive, I could open it (of course without the files that I have on the external disk). When I connect the drive and try to load them again QGIS just crash.

Tried reinstalling, but happens the same problem, as well as when I create a new project and try to load those files. Does anyone know how to fix it??

I am having a long error message that I can replicate, just pasting the next few lines but let me know which lines should I be posting.

> Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
> Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
> Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
> Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
> Application Specific Information:
> abort() called >

Comment: Have you tried transfering the files from your ext. drive to your system? Can you load them into QGIS from there without crashing?

Comment: Yes I have tried that, and I could load the files another folder. 
I've figured it out that only happens with the files from 2 folders, they are raster images of about 144 mb each (topographic maps). I can load other .tif from the external drive succesfully.